# Macos nginx php 7.3 wordpress error in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, macos, nginx, php-7.3

I have just updated to use php7.3 with nginx 1.17.0 on my Macos Mojave using brew. PHP-FPM is configured to use port 9073 and my sample website nginx configuration is like that:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9073
    fastcgi_index  index.php
}
```

Before the update using same configuration everything was working fine. At the moment All frontend pages works, but when i try to access domain/wp-admin/ I am getting 502 error. This is happening just to that route. On the error log i see:

```
kevent reported about an closed connection 54: Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1
```

and the php-fpm is restarting. I really don't know what to do now. Thank you for your help

Comment: [ask] Can you run any php code?

Comment: php works fine! wordpress sites frontend are working. Also info.php server info page is working as well

Comment: All installations happened through brew (also downgraded to PHP7.2) but php-fpm restart unexpectedly when access ONLY /wp-admin route of my wordpress website. All frontend wordpress pages works fine and and info.php is working as well.

On php.ini we have added xdebug using pecl. All other settings are the default ones:

zend_extension=“xdebug.so”
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
extension=“redis.so”

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated to Macos Mojave and PHP7.3 using nginx. All installations happened through brew (also downgraded to PHP7.2) but php-fpm restart unexpectedly when access ONLY /wp-admin route of my wordpress website. All frontend wordpress pages works fine and and info.php is working as well.

On php.ini we have added xdebug using pecl. All other settings are the default ones:

```
zend_extension=“xdebug.so”
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
extension=“redis.so”
```

php-fpm log using log_level=debug when accessing /wp-admin show “exited on signal 11” and php-fpm service restarts:

```
[25-Jun-2019 22:26:01.104274] DEBUG: pid 47, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 378: [pool www] currently 1 active children, 1 spare children, 2 running children. Spawning rate 1
[25-Jun-2019 22:26:01.839904] DEBUG: pid 47, fpm_got_signal(), line 75: received SIGCHLD
[25-Jun-2019 22:26:01.839968] WARNING: pid 47, fpm_children_bury(), line 256: [pool www] child 980 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 21.933941 seconds from start
[25-Jun-2019 22:26:01.841578] NOTICE: pid 47, fpm_children_make(), line 425: [pool www] child 1037 started
[25-Jun-2019 22:26:01.845627] DEBUG: pid 47, fpm_event_loop(), line 418: event module triggered 1 events [25-Jun-2019 22:26:02.176554] DEBUG: pid 47, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 378: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 2 spare children, 2 running children. Spawning rate 1
```